# NEST Elasticsearch Reindex examples

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

my objective is to reindex an index with 10 million shards for the purposes of changing field mappings to facilitate significant terms analysis.

My problem is that I am having trouble using the NEST library to perform a re-index, and the documentation is (very) limited. If possible I need an example of the following in use:

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/search/scroll.html

http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/core/bulk.html

Comment: Now can use serverside reindex via NEST.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NEST provides a nice `Reindex` method you can use, although the documentation is lacking.  I've used it in a very rough-and-ready fashion with this ad-hoc WinForms code.

```
    private ElasticClient client;
    private double count;

    private void reindex_Completed()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

    private void reindex_Next(IReindexResponse<object> obj)
    {
        count += obj.BulkResponse.Items.Count();
        var progress = 100 * count / (double)obj.SearchResponse.Total;
        progressBar1.Value = (int)progress;
    }

    private void reindex_Error(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count = 0;

        var reindex = client.Reindex<object>(r => r.FromIndex(fromIndex.Text).NewIndexName(toIndex.Text).Scroll("10s"));

        var o = new ReindexObserver<object>(onError: reindex_Error, onNext: reindex_Next, completed: reindex_Completed);
        reindex.Subscribe(o);
    }
```

And I've just found the blog post that showed me how to do it: http://thomasardal.com/elasticsearch-migrations-with-c-and-nest/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I'll see what I can do with it!

Comment: The important thing for me was calling reindex.Subscribe() and watching exceptions being thrown.  This was failing silently for me for two reasons: 1) Index already exists and 2) The current index does not contain any documents.

Comment: If I don't create the new index in the reindex() call, a ReindexException is raised, why is that happening?

Comment: or try https://www.nuget.org/packages/ElasticsearchCRUD/ and follow this blog https://damienbod.com/2014/11/07/live-reindex-in-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the `NEST` implementation is not quite what I expected. In my opinion it's a bit over-engineered for possibly the most common use case.

Alot of people just want to update their mappings with zero downtime...

In my case - I had already taken care of creating the index with all its settings and mappings, but `NEST` insists that it must create a new index when reindexing. That among many other things. Too many other things.

I found it much less complicated to just implement directly - since NEST already has `Search`, `Scroll`, and `Bulk` methods. (this is adopted from `NEST`'s implementation):

```
// Assuming you have already created and setup the index yourself
public void Reindex(ElasticClient client, string aliasName, string currentIndexName, string nextIndexName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reindexing documents to new index...");
    var searchResult = client.Search<object>(s => s.Index(currentIndexName).AllTypes().From(0).Size(100).Query(q => q.MatchAll()).SearchType(SearchType.Scan).Scroll("2m"));
    if (searchResult.Total <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Existing index has no documents, nothing to reindex.");
    }
    else
    {
        var page = 0;
        IBulkResponse bulkResponse = null;
        do
        {
            var result = searchResult;
            searchResult = client.Scroll<object>(s => s.Scroll("2m").ScrollId(result.ScrollId));
            if (searchResult.Documents != null && searchResult.Documents.Any())
            {
                searchResult.ThrowOnError("reindex scroll " + page);
                bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b =>
                {
                    foreach (var hit in searchResult.Hits)
                    {
                        b.Index<object>(bi => bi.Document(hit.Source).Type(hit.Type).Index(nextIndexName).Id(hit.Id));
                    }

                    return b;
                }).ThrowOnError("reindex page " + page);
                Console.WriteLine("Reindexing progress: " + (page + 1) * 100);
            }

            ++page;
        }
        while (searchResult.IsValid && bulkResponse != null && bulkResponse.IsValid && searchResult.Documents != null && searchResult.Documents.Any());
        Console.WriteLine("Reindexing complete!");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Updating alias to point to new index...");
    client.Alias(a => a
        .Add(aa => aa.Alias(aliasName).Index(nextIndexName))
        .Remove(aa => aa.Alias(aliasName).Index(currentIndexName)));

    // TODO: Don't forget to delete the old index if you want
}
```

And the `ThrowOnError` extension method in case you want it:

```
public static T ThrowOnError<T>(this T response, string actionDescription = null) where T : IResponse
{
    if (!response.IsValid)
    {
        throw new CustomExceptionOfYourChoice(actionDescription == null ? string.Empty : "Failed to " + actionDescription + ": " + response.ServerError.Error);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I second Ben Wilde's answer above.  Better to have full control over index creation and the re-index process.

What's missing from Ben's code is support for parent/child relationship.   Here is my code to fix that:

Replace the following lines:

```
foreach (var hit in searchResult.Hits)
{
    b.Index<object>(bi => bi.Document(hit.Source).Type(hit.Type).Index(nextIndexName).Id(hit.Id));
}
```

With this:

```
foreach (var hit in searchResult.Hits)
{
    var jo = hit.Source as JObject;
    JToken jt;
    if(jo != null && jo.TryGetValue("parentId", out jt))
    {
        // Document is child-document => add parent reference
        string parentId = (string)jt;
        b.Index<object>(bi => bi.Document(hit.Source).Type(hit.Type).Index(nextIndexName).Id(hit.Id).Parent(parentId));
    }
    else
    {
        b.Index<object>(bi => bi.Document(hit.Source).Type(hit.Type).Index(nextIndexName).Id(hit.Id));
    }                                
}
```