# Blocking an index for readonly operations, makes elasticsearch left in an inconsistent state

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I want to block an index from write operations if I have to make a reindex process of this index.
This both posts([elasticsearch migrations with c and nest](http://thomasardal.com/elasticsearch-migrations-with-c-and-nest/) & [NEST Elasticsearch Reindex examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25914346/553029)) were very helpful, but as suggested by [this third one](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/09/elasticsearch-zero-downtime-reindexing-problems-solutions/), you can lost updates and deletes in the middle of this process.
I have tried blocking the index from write operations, using the setting in elasticsearch but I found some issues trying this.
I used the `UpdateSettings` api of Nest to change the settings `blocks.read_only`, `blocks.metadata`, `blocks.read` and `blocks.write`:

```
var client = CreateElasticClient(); // A wrapper method of ElasticClient()
var response = client.UpdateSettings(r => r
                    .Index(IndexName)
                    .BlockReadonly()
                    .BlocksMetadata()
                    .BlocksRead()
                    .BlocksWrite()
                    );
```

If I set the settings `blocks.read_only`, `blocks.metadata`, `blocks.read` to true (value set by default), then the index won't accept write operations, but also read operations are not allow either, to be precise, I had to reinstall elasticsearch in three occasions today, because I couldn't do anything else with it after changing these settings.
Setting `blocks.write` to true won't have any effect, I can read the index, but also I can write it.
**QUESTION**
So, my question is, how should I do this (block the index from write operations while it been reindexed)?

Comment: Just leave this UpdateSettingsDescriptor with .BlocksWrite(). Worked for me. Maybe you are getting error in response when you are using only .BlockWrite(). Would like to share?

Comment: Hi @Rob I used two combinations in the UpdateSettingDescriptor, and the last one was using only the BlocksWrite(), but even then I was able to write in the index.

Comment: Are you sure UpdateSettings request didn't return error? I was able to block writes to an index by calling .BlockWrite() on UpdateSettings request, it was working like a charm. May you share more details: ES, NEST version, how do you create ElasticClient etc?

Comment: @Rob I use ES 1.5.1, last version of Nest too. The response of UpdateSetting is successful. Even when I check the index setting the block.write is set to true. That's why I don't post more details, because everything was made by the manual, and the modification of the setting is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared simple example. Maybe it will put some light on your problem.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var indexName = "indexname";
        var indexName2 = "indexname2";

        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri).SetDefaultIndex(indexName).EnableTrace();
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var indicesResponse = client.DeleteIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName));
        var indicesResponse2 = client.DeleteIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName2));

        client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).AddMapping<Document>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));

        client.Index(new Document {Id = 1});

        client.Refresh();

        var acknowledgedResponse = client.UpdateSettings(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).BlocksWrite());

        var observable = client.Reindex<Document>(descriptor => descriptor.FromIndex(indexName).ToIndex(indexName2));
        observable.Subscribe(new ReindexObserver<Document>(response => Console.WriteLine(response.IsValid),
            Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Done")));

        var documentToAdd = new Document { Id = 2, Name = "new" };

        var indexResponse = client.Index(documentToAdd);

        //indexResponse -> can't index new document with message: blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/8/index write (api)];

        var getResponse = client.Get<Document>(descriptor => descriptor.Id(1));

        //getResponse -> still can read from index

        var acknowledgedResponse2 = client.UpdateSettings(descriptor => descriptor.Index(indexName).BlocksWrite(false));

        var indexResponse2 = client.Index(documentToAdd);

        //indexResponse2 -> now I can add new document to my index

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this solution totally works, the only difference with my code is that I tried to insert document from a different thread, and it do it without fail. I checked the index setting and the block.write is set to true, like is when I run your solution. I'm marking this as the accepted answer because it works, but I need to do more research about it.

Answer (score 0):

Reindexing could become a time consuming process as the data grows. Even if there was a way to block writes, how are you planning to reapply the lost writes? (if they are new documents that are not captured by the reindex)

Elasticsearch has support for aliases which can be used for this. see [Aliases](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html). As you rebuild the index you could still capture all the writes and still support read operations using these. Here is an useful link which details some of the approaches. [Reindex options](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/09/elasticsearch-zero-downtime-reindexing-problems-solutions/)

Comment: Hi @jrao77, thanks for the answer. about it, the third post I mentioned in my question, match the link you suggest for reindexing options. It is very useful, but does not show any explicit solution.